# Python xpath - Get text from two different childs in a single operation

Tags: python, xpath

I have this block of html (This is not the whole html):

```
<div class="self-clear">
    <div class="item-wrap self-clear float-left">
        <h2>
            Doran's Start
            <span class="notes tooltip"></span>
        </h2>
        <div class="self-clear item-group">
    <div class="main-items float-left ">
        <a href="/league-of-legends/item/dorans-ring-25">
            <div class="item ajax-tooltip {t:'Item',i:'25'}">
            <div class="item-title">
                <span class="ajax-tooltip {t:'Item',i:'25'}">Doran's Ring</span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

and I want to get the text inside `<h2>` and inside each `<div>` in the same operation; I tried doing it like:

```
    for build_names in guide_page.xpath(".//div[@class='self-clear mb10']/div/div[2]/div/h2/text() and "
                                        ".//div[@class='self-clear mb10']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a/div[2]"
                                        "/text()"):
```

But well, that was not correct... Is it possible to do that?

I need some things out of that operation above but when I do it as two different loops I get an output like:

```
String from the first for loop
String from the first for loop

String from the second for loop... etc, etc.
```

I'd like it to be:

```
String from the first loop
String from the second loop
String from the first loop
String from the second loop and so on
```

If I didn't explain myself too clear please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Well, neither `<h2>` nor the `<div>`s of your sample HTML have any text nodes (except space). So a [mcve] would be helpful for us to approach your problem.

Comment: @zx485 Updated  :)

Comment: shouldn't be `or` instead of `and` ?

Comment: @furas I can try but I want the text of both, not either `h2` or `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if is anything else behind this so I won't be able to explain it that much; I managed to solve it by doing it this way:

```
    for build_names in guide_page.xpath(".//div[@class='item-wrap self-clear float-left']"):
        for x in build_names.xpath("h2/text()"):
            print(x)

        for y in build_names.xpath("div/div/a/div[2]/span/text()"):
            print(y)
```

This outputs:

```
Doran's Start #1st
Boots of Speed #2nd
Health Potion #2nd
Warding Totem #2nd


Morellonomicon #1st
Sorcerer's Shoes #2nd
Rylai's Crystal Scepter #2nd
Rabadon's Deathcap #2nd
Void Staff #2nd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use union (`|`) operator to combine two XPath expressions into one :

```
query = '''.//div[@class='self-clear mb10']/div/div[2]/div/h2/text() | 
           .//div[@class='self-clear mb10']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a/div[2]/text()'''
for build_names in guide_page.xpath(query):
    ....
```